# How to make parent div auto height relatively browser width?

Tags: html, css

I want to make a div's height changeable relatively browser width, like if we create a div `width:100%;` and inside put img `width:100%; height:auto;`, so in this case height of div is changeable relatively height of img, that re-sizing from window width.

But in my case i don't want to put img inside parent div,(inside is also div width text block) i want to make behavior of parent div, like inside is img.

How to get it? It is possible  ?

```css
.hero-section-inner {
  width: 100%;
}
.hero-section-inner img,
.hero-section-inner-half img {
  width: 100%!important;
  height: auto!important;
}
.hero-section-inner-half {
  width: 50%;
  margin-top: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="hero-section-inner">
  <img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-4769" src="http://www.ev-interiordesign.ru/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/about-header.jpg">
</div>
<div class="hero-section-inner-half">
  <img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-4769" src="http://www.ev-interiordesign.ru/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/about-header.jpg">
</div>
```

So it's example with img.

Comment: Share your code with us.

Comment: do you want it as a background image?or just as a small image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

padding (and margin) in percentage is always relative to width

```
.container {
  width: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 54%; // relative to width
  background: red;
  height:0;
}
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/17j0Lngb/1/)

you might be interested in looking at `vh` and `vw` css units

Answer (score 0):

If you use `float:left;` to your div, It'll get image with and height automatically. Also, `float:left;` is important for responsive pages.

**So,**

```
.hero-section-inner {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Sure, you can make this. Just set the div like display:block, you can visit http://www.28uv.com/extreme-income-ninja/2-building-simple-funnel/ for more details and examples.